# Thread-aware heap allocation tracking with JVMTI

Tags: java, jvmti

Writing a profiling I would also implement the typical task of heap profiling. Specifically I would like to track, which thread has allocated how much data? Using JVMTI I thought it's sufficient to hook to the events *VM Object Allocation* and *Object Free*. Sadly I read the first event is not triggered due to calls made to `new`.

The last idea I had was to check teh event *MethodExit* if its name is `<init>` and thus declare this call as an object allocation. However, within this event I cannot get the object and thus I cannot invoke `GetObjectSize`.

Simply iterating over the heap, bears no information regarding which object was allocated by which thread. Does anyone have an idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there some reason you can't call `GetObjectSize` from the `MethodEntry` event for a constructor?

If you're interested in executing code before a method returns, then you can listen for the `MethodEntry` event, and if the method is named `<init>`, you can call `NotifyFramePop` to listen for the `FramePop` event for the current frame. This event is similar to the `MethodExit` event, but occurs before the method returns so you can still get the `this` object.

Answer (score 3):

A quick glance into the _new implementation of the Hotspot VM (templateTable_x86_64.cpp) seems to indicate, that _new doesn't offer any hooks for JVMTI (not even in the slow case it seems). So if your  trick doesn't work, I don't see any other possibility - but I'm by no means an expert for JVMTI.

I assume compiling your own Hotspot VM with a small patch isn't especially useful for you?

Comment: No, since I am writing a general JVM profiler of my own. Though thanks for looking into it +1 This just affirms my suspicion.

Answer (score 3):

This [heapTracker demo](http://acm2010.cct.lsu.edu/localdoc/java/6-jdk/demo/jvmti/) illustrates you how to track all the objects in the heap. 
Because the [VMObjectAlloc Event](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#VMObjectAlloc) is sent only when reflection occurs, the demo uses ByteCodeInstrument to track new object allocation.

---

You can use getCurrentThread function to know which thread the object is belong to.